# adding security to a jsp login page

Tags: jsp, authentication, security

I am working on adding security to a jsp login page. Can somebody please tell me which types of security that i can add to my login page. It would be nice if you could refer me some good links for doing this.

I want to implement the following things:

1. I want to provide SSL protected communication.
2. I want to implement policies for strong password such as minimum number of characters and presence of ateast one uppercase and one special character.
3. I want to implement idle timeout feature with a warning message before doing actual logout.
4. I want to encrypt password while storing it into database.
5. I want to provide to provide warnings for too many logging in attempts with the same username.
6. I want to prevent users from accessing out of authorization features.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What kind of security do you want to add? Do you want SSL-protected communication? Do you want password policies to be enforced? Do you want to block accounts with too many failed attempts? Do you want to hash passwords in the database? security is a too broad term for us to be able to help.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Sorry. I have updated by question with proper needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Spring and Spring Security. It's very powerful and well established library for (but not restricted to) web applications.

Comment: Can you give me some good links about that. I am new to this. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri: Visit http://www.springsource.com/developer/spring. Also http://www.springsource.org/documentation, also http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf